# how dose jemalloc on ARM/Linux

Tags: c, linux, arm

How will the **jemalloc** (jemalloc-3.4.0) be transplanted onto the **ARM**?

If I modify

```
#define CPU_SPINWAIT asm volatile("pause")
```

to

```
#define CPU_SPINWAIT asm volatile("NOP")
```

it works. **But I found jemalloc using more time... Why?**

Comment: Read the documentation. People write them for many reasons, and one of it is your question.

Comment: I modify "#define CPU_SPINWAIT __asm__ volatile("pause")" TO "#define CPU_SPINWAIT __asm__ volatile("NOP"),and sucess.but i found jemalloc using a more time, why?
"

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of this site http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/  (seems to be official site)

you can find this e-mail: **jasone@canonware.com** which you can contact for support.